# How to escape from inside a Handlebars each loop?

Tags: iteration, each, handlebars.js

I am iterating over an array using Handlebars' each helper, but when I'm inside of the loop, how do I reference a mixin that does not contain an object in the looping array?

Answer (score 0):

Variables in handlebars are accessed via depth based paths. Therefore, variables outside #each can be accessed using **{{../variable_name}}**